# Python Kedro PySpark : py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, pyspark, kedro

it's my first project using kedro with Pyspark and I have an issue. I work with the new Mac (M1). When I do  `spark-shell` in the terminal, spark is successfully installed and I have the right output (welcome to spark version 3.2.1 with the picture). However, I tried to run spark using Kedro project, I have a trouble. I tried to find solutions thanks to stack overflow discussion but nothing linked with this.

Version:

- Python : 3.8
- Java : openjdk version "18" 2022-03-22
- PySpark : 3.2.1

Spark conf :

```
spark.driver.maxResultSize: 3g
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled: true
```

And in my project context of Kedro :

```
class ProjectContext(KedroContext):
    """A subclass of KedroContext to add Spark initialisation for the pipeline."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        package_name: str,
        project_path: Union[Path, str],
        env: str = None,
        extra_params: Dict[str, Any] = None,
    ):
        super().__init__(package_name, project_path, env, extra_params)
        if not os.getenv('DISABLE_SPARK'):
            self.init_spark_session()

    def init_spark_session(self) -> None:
        """Initialises a SparkSession using the config
        defined in project's conf folder.
        """

        parameters = self.config_loader.get("spark*", "spark*/**")
        spark_conf = SparkConf().setAll(parameters.items())

        # Initialise the spark session
        spark_session_conf = (
            SparkSession.builder.appName(self.package_name)
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .config(conf=spark_conf)
            .master("local[*]")
        )
        _spark_session = spark_session_conf.getOrCreate()
```

When I run it, I have this error :

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x3c60b7e7) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x3c60b7e7
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<init>(StorageUtils.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

In my terminal, I adapted the commands to match my Python path :

```
export HOMEBREW_OPT="/opt/homebrew/opt"
export JAVA_HOME="$HOMEBREW_OPT/openjdk/"
export SPARK_HOME="$HOMEBREW_OPT/apache-spark/libexec"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME:$SPARK_HOME:$PATH"
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=localhost
```

Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Mathilde Roblot thanks for the detailed report -

The specific error '`cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module`' sticks out to me.

Googling suggests that you may be retrieving the wrong Java (not 8.0 as required by spark)

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49453770/2010808
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/69851663/2010808

Answer (score 1):

You can use some `SparkConf` to set needed `--add-opens` see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71855571/13547620.

Answer (score 0):

this also happens when your spark env libs are not being picked up by Kedro or Kedro is not able to find spark in your env.

QQ : are using an IDE like PyCharm , if that is the case , you might need to go to preferences and embed your env variables. I had faced the same problem and setting the env variables from the project preferences helped me

Hope this helps